# Combining multiple for loops into single iterator

Tags: c++, loops, c++14

Say I have a nest for loop like

```
for (int x = xstart; x < xend; x++){
    for (int y = ystart; y < yend; y++){
        for (int z = zstart; z < zend; z++){
            function_doing_stuff(std::make_tuple(x, y, z));
        }
    }
}
```

and would like to transform it into

```
MyRange range(xstart,xend,ystart,yend, zstart,zend);
for (auto point : range){
    function_doing_stuff(point);
}
```

How would I write the MyRange class to be as efficient as the nested for loops?
The motivation for this is to be able to use std algorithms (such as transform, accumulate, etc), and to create code that is largely dimension agnostic.

By having an iterator, it would be easy to create templated functions that operate over a range of 1d, 2d or 3d points.

Code base is currently C++14.

EDIT:

Writing clear questions is hard. I'll try to clarify.
My problem is not writing an iterator, that I can do. Instead, the problem is one of performance: Is it possible to make an iterator that is as fast as the nested for loops?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: shouldn't the second for be on `y`?

Comment: Good use for templates.

Comment: simply write a iterator that when dereferences returns a tuple. Note that most algorithms you wont be able to use as the tuple can only be read.  What did you try? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you care about performance, you should forget about combining iterators for the foreseeable future. The central problem is that compilers cannot yet untangle the mess and figure out that there are 3 independent variables in it, much less perform any loop interchange or unrolling or fusion.

If you must use ranges, use simple ones that the compiler can see through:

```
for (int const x : boost::irange<int>(xstart,xend))
    for (int const y : boost::irange<int>(ystart,yend))
        for (int const z : boost::irange<int>(zstart,zend))
            function_doing_stuff(x, y, z);
```

Alternatively, you can actually pass your functor and the boost ranges to a template:

```
template <typename Func, typename Range0, typename Range1, typename Range2>
void apply_ranges (Func func, Range0 r0, Range1 r1, Range2 r2)
{
     for (auto const i0 : r0)
         for (auto const i1 : r1)
             for (auto const i2 : r2)
                 func (i0, i1, i2);
}
```

If you **truly** care about performance, then you should not contort your code with complicated ranges, because they make it harder to untangle later when you want to rewrite them in AVX intrinsics.

Comment: Couldn't I use ranges with omp simd tough? Or will it only work with old-school index for loops?

Comment: @LKlevin Maybe? Compile it with `-S` to find out what assembly it actually gives you. IMO most of the real work done in this space involve optimizing data layout, not in prettier iterators.

Answer (score 6):

With [range/v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
auto xs = ranges::view::iota(xstart, xend);
auto ys = ranges::view::iota(ystart, yend);
auto zs = ranges::view::iota(zstart, zend);
for (const auto& point : ranges::view::cartesian_product(xs, ys, zs)){
    function_doing_stuff(point);
}
```

Comment: Nice and concise solution. Sadly the speed is pretty bad compared with nested for loops.  ~3000ns for the iterator approach vs 44ns for trivial for loops.

Answer (score 5):

You can introduce your own class as

```
class myClass {
  public:
    myClass (int x, int y, int z):m_x(x) , m_y(y), m_z(z){};
  private: 
    int m_x, m_y, m_z;

}
```

and then initialize a `std::vector<myClass>` with your triple loop

```
std::vector<myClass> myVec;
myVec.reserve((xend-xstart)*(yend-ystart)*(zend-zstart)); // alloc memory only once;
for (int x = ystart; x < xend; x++){
    for (int y = xstart; y < yend; y++){ // I assume you have a copy paste error here
        for (int z = zstart; z < zend; z++){
            myVec.push_back({x,y,z})
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use all the nice std algorithms with the `std::vector<myClass> myVec`. With the syntactic sugar

```
using MyRange = std::vector<MyClass>;
```

and

```
MyRange makeMyRange(int xstart, int xend, int ystart, int yend, int zstart,int zend) {
    MyRange myVec;
    // loop from above
    return MyRange;
}
```

you can write

```
const MyRange range = makeMyRange(xstart, xend, ystart, yend, zstart, zend);
for (auto point : range){
    function_doing_stuff(point);
}
```

With the new move semantics this wont create unneeded copies. Please note, that the interface to this function is rather bad. Perhaps rather use 3 pairs of int, denoting the x,y,z interval.

Perhaps you change the names to something meaningful (e.g.myClass could be Point).

Answer (score 5):

Another option, which directly transplants whatever looping code, is to use a [Coroutine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/asymmetric.html). This emulates `yield` from Python or C#.

```
using point = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
using coro = boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<point>;

coro::pull_type points(
    [&](coro::push_type& yield){
        for (int x = xstart; x < xend; x++){
            for (int y = ystart; y < yend; y++){
                for (int z = zstart; z < zend; z++){
                    yield(std::make_tuple(x, y, z));
                }
            }
        }
    });

for(auto p : points)
    function_doing_stuff(p);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bare-bones implementation that does not use any advanced language features or other libraries.  The performance should be pretty close to the for loop version.

```
#include <tuple>

class MyRange {
public:
    typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> valtype;
    MyRange(int xstart, int xend, int ystart, int yend, int zstart, int zend): xstart(xstart), xend(xend), ystart(ystart), yend(yend), zstart(zstart), zend(zend) {
    }

    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator(MyRange &c): me(c) {
            curvalue = std::make_tuple(me.xstart, me.ystart, me.zstart);
        }
        iterator(MyRange &c, bool end): me(c) {
            curvalue = std::make_tuple(end ? me.xend : me.xstart, me.ystart, me.zstart);
        }
        valtype operator*() {
            return curvalue;
        }
        iterator &operator++() {
            if (++std::get<2>(curvalue) == me.zend) {
                std::get<2>(curvalue) = me.zstart;
                if (++std::get<1>(curvalue) == me.yend) {
                    std::get<1>(curvalue) = me.ystart;
                    ++std::get<0>(curvalue);
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator &other) const {
            return curvalue == other.curvalue;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const {
            return curvalue != other.curvalue;
        }
    private:
        MyRange &me;
        valtype curvalue;
    };

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(*this);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(*this, true);
    }

private:
    int xstart, xend;
    int ystart, yend;
    int zstart, zend;
};
```

And an example of usage:

```
#include <iostream>

void display(std::tuple<int, int, int> v) {
    std::cout << "(" << std::get<0>(v) << ", " << std::get<1>(v) << ", " << std::get<2>(v) << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    MyRange c(1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 9);
    for (auto v: c) {
        display(v);
    }
}
```

I've left off things like const iterators, possible `operator+=`, decrementing, post increment, etc.  They've been left as an exercise for the reader.

It stores the initial values, then increments each value in turn, rolling it back and incrementing the next when it get to the end value.  It's a bit like incrementing a multi-digit number.

Comment: I did something similar, but was able to get *better* performance by doing the operator== and sentinel iterator a bit different. Specifically instead of a reference to MyRange I had a pointer to MyRange and made the sentinel end() iterator have this as NULL (with the operator++ setting the pointer to NULL when we reach the end). This means that the operator== can first check if the pointer is NULL or not rather than comparing the tuple values. Some sprinkling of BOOST_LIKELY() to hint the compiler as to which branches were most likely was also required.

Answer (score 1):

Using `boost::iterator_facade` for simplicity, you can spell out all the required members.

First we have a class that iterates N-dimensional indexes as `std::array<std::size_t, N>`

```
template<std::size_t N>
class indexes_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<indexes_iterator, std::array<std::size_t, N>>
{
public:
    template<typename... Dims>
    indexes_iterator(Dims... dims) : dims{ dims... }, values{} {}

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() { advance(1); }
    void decrement() { advance(-1); }

    void advance(int n) 
    { 
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        { 
            int next = ((values[i] + n) % dims[i]); 
            n = (n \ dims[i]) + (next < value); 
            values[i] = next;
        }
    }

    std::size_t distance(indexes_iterator const & other) const
    {
        std::size_t result = 0, mul = 1;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < dims; ++i)
        {
             result += mul * other[i] - values[i];
             mul *= ends[i];
        }
    }

    bool equal(indexes_iterator const& other) const
    {
        return values == other.values;
    }

    std::array<std::size_t, N> & dereference() const { return values; }

    std::array<std::size_t, N> ends;
    std::array<std::size_t, N> values;
}
```

Then we use that to make something similar to a `boost::zip_iterator`, but instead of advancing all together we add our indexes.

```
template <typename... Iterators>
class product_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<product_iterator<Iterators...>, const std::tuple<decltype(*std::declval<Iterators>())...>, boost::random_access_traversal_tag>
{
    using ref = std::tuple<decltype(*std::declval<Iterators>())...>;
public:
    product_iterator(Iterators ... ends) : indexes() , iterators(std::make_tuple(ends...)) {}
    template <typename ... Sizes>
    product_iterator(Iterators ... begins, Sizes ... sizes) 
      : indexes(sizes...), 
        iterators(begins...) 
    {}
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    ref dereference_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...> idxs) const
    {
        auto offs = offset(idxs);
        return { *std::get<Is>(offs)... };
    }

    ref dereference() const
    { 
        return dereference_impl(std::index_sequence_for<Iterators...>{}); 
    }

    void increment() { ++indexes; }
    void decrement() { --indexes; }
    void advance(int n) { indexes += n; }

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    std::tuple<Iterators...> offset(std::index_sequence<Is...>) const
    {
        auto idxs = *indexes;
        return { (std::get<Is>(iterators) + std::get<Is>(idxs))... };
    }

    bool equal(product_iterator const & other) const 
    {
        return offset(std::index_sequence_for<Iterators...>{}) 
            == other.offset(std::index_sequence_for<Iterators...>{}); 
    }

    indexes_iterator<sizeof...(Iterators)> indexes;
    std::tuple<Iterators...> iterators;
};
```

Then we wrap it up in a `boost::iterator_range`

```
template <typename... Ranges>
auto make_product_range(Ranges&&... rngs)
{
    product_iterator<decltype(begin(rngs))...> b(begin(rngs)..., std::distance(std::begin(rngs), std::end(rngs))...);
    product_iterator<decltype(begin(rngs))...> e(end(rngs)...);
    return boost::iterator_range<product_iterator<decltype(begin(rngs))...>>(b, e);
}

int main()
{
    using ranges::view::iota;
    for (auto p : make_product_range(iota(xstart, xend), iota(ystart, yend), iota(zstart, zend)))
        // ...
    return 0;
}
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jms8nF)

Comment: I **think** this does what I want, but I can't get it to compile. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/RmiGzO)

Comment: I am unsure why, but the code you posted never actually iterate (or rather, iterates 0 times). I think I understand your code, but what the flaw is escapes me.

Comment: It might be that I'm lacking a distance function. It's an effort to get it symmetric. `boost::zip_iterator` has a tuple of iterators as it's template parameter, rather than a parameter pack. I might have made things harder by going for a parameter pack.

Answer (score 0):

Just a very simplified version that will be as efficient as a for loop:

```
#include <tuple>

struct iterator{
  int x;
  int x_start;
  int x_end;
  int y;
  int y_start;
  int y_end;
  int z;
  constexpr auto
  operator*() const{
    return std::tuple{x,y,z};
    }
  constexpr iterator&
  operator++ [[gnu::always_inline]](){
    ++x;
    if (x==x_end){
      x=x_start;
      ++y;
      if (y==y_end) {
        ++z;
        y=y_start;
        }
      }
    return *this;
    }
  constexpr iterator
  operator++(int){
    auto old=*this;
    operator++();
    return old;
    }
  };
struct sentinel{
  int z_end;
  friend constexpr bool
  operator == (const iterator& x,const sentinel& s){
    return x.z==s.z_end;
    }
  friend constexpr bool
  operator == (const sentinel& a,const iterator& x){
    return x==a;
    }
  friend constexpr bool
  operator != (const iterator& x,const sentinel& a){
    return !(x==a);
    }
  friend constexpr bool
  operator != (const sentinel& a,const iterator& x){
    return !(x==a);
    }
  };

struct range{
  iterator start;
  sentinel finish;
  constexpr auto
  begin() const{
    return start;
    }
  constexpr auto
  end()const{
    return finish;
    }
  };

void func(int,int,int);

void test(const range& r){
  for(auto [x,y,z]: r)
    func(x,y,z);
  }
void test(int x_start,int x_end,int y_start,int y_end,int z_start,int z_end){
  for(int z=z_start;z<z_end;++z)
    for(int y=y_start;y<y_end;++y)
      for(int x=x_start;x<x_end;++x)
        func(x,y,z);
  }
```

The advantage over 1201ProgramAlarm answer is the faster test performed at each iteration thanks to the use of a sentinel.